# PostgreSQL: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, thingsboard, postgresql-12

I have a ThingsBoard Professional Edition setup using AWS EC2 instance. The database is PostgreSQL-12. I tend to get the following error: `FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"`  when trying to log into the remote database server on pgAdmin4.

Here is a screenshot of the error shown when attempting to log in to server created on pgAdmin4.
[image: Connect to server error]
Here is how I configured the remote database server (where Host name/address is the Public IPv4 of my EC2 instance).
[image: Create Server]

In `postgresql.conf`, I have replaced the line listen_address='127.0.0.1' with `listen_addresses='*'`.
In `pg_hba.conf`, I added `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`.
Here is a screenshot of my pg_hba.conf file:
[image: pg_hba.conf]
I have also set the password for the user 'postgres' using the psql command `#\password`.

Here is what is shown in thingboard.log when I run the command:
`cat /var/log/thingsboard/thingsboard.log | grep ERROR`
[image: log file]

Partial screenshot of `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log` shows the following:
[image: postgresql log]

I constantly have to use `#ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD ‘<password>’;` to be able to overcome this error but the error tends to return when I restart my local Windows machine.

Answer (score 2):

That must be done by some software other than PostgreSQL.

Configure logging by setting `log_statement = 'ddl'` in `postgresql.conf` and restarting the database. Then you can more easily figure out when and by which software your password gets changed.

Additionally, configure `pg_hba.conf` to not allow passwordless connections from anywhere, then change the password. You may see some component start to complain - that component may be at fault.